# how to exit "python manage.py runserver" in windows

Tags: django, windows, cmd

How can I exit from the command line after executing:

```
python manage.py run server 8080
```

I already tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> but neither worked. Using gitbash instead of cmd changed nothing.

I am using Windows (64 bit).

[image: A Screenshot from my command line]

Comment: did you try `Ctrl + C`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd> is the magic combination if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> doesn't work.

Comment: @asynts it was a pebkac ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Try <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> instead of just <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> as this will Capitalize the C.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Ctrl+C should work. It works in Linux terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl-C works in most instances, you could also try Ctrl-D if it does not.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10 powershell, we use `Ctrl + Shift + C` ;note that this is capital C here; for exiting after `python manage.py runserver`  and returning to prompt.